# How to use the MCMC method for multivariate distributions?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I wish to find the posterior of a joint distribution of 4 parameters whose prior and likelihoods are known, but I do not understand how to accept and reject samples, in any other case other than single variable cases used in Metropolis-Hastings.
I am a mathematics undergrad, and I would be really grateful if you could direct me to some good literature.

Thanking you in advance.

PS:- This is for a problem in Operations Research(Reliability Theory). If you require a more specific description of the problem statement, please let me know.

Comment: You can apply the univariate approach for each variable, unless the 4 parameters should satisfy some restriction (e.g. their sum is zero).

Comment: Hi @Aravind, just a question to make sure I understood your problem correctly : you wish to compute the posterior distribution of having four parameters $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$, but the classical description of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm only holds for the posterior of a single parameter $\theta$ (what you call the "single variate case"). Is that correct ?

Comment: Thanks for asking @CamilleGontier. Yes! that's exactly what I wish to know. Is there any other MCMC method out there that can help me out. I tried using the Gibbs Sampling approach but am confused on how to use it in my specific problem

Comment: You actually just need priors and a likelihood for all parameters (so that you can check whether log-prior + log-likelihood at a newly proposed parameters value compares to the previous value of the Markov chain) and some reasonable way of making proposals (e.g. for multiple independent parameters, you could use a multivariate normal in the MH-algorithm). Everything else remains the same, simply the single value becomes a vector. Not sure whether that clarifies what you are struggling with.

Comment: PS: If you really just want to sample (and it's less about understanding/showing how you do it on paper), just using Stan (e.g. via the rstan package in R) tends to be a very good solution (unless you have discrete parameters you cannot integrate out).

Comment: @Aravind Let us know if you have further questions or need more explanation. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: You may use Gibbs Sampling, in this case you need the conditional PDFs that depends on the number of the parameters in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm is applicable whatever the dimension of $\theta$. Finding the posterior of the joint distribution of $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$, and $\theta_4$, is equivalent to finding the posterior distribution of $\Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a $4 \times 1$ vector with $\Theta = [\theta_1 \ \theta_2 \ \theta_3 \ \theta_4]$.

Let's apply it to the formalism of the [Wikipedia article on the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Step-by-step_instructions). Then the most recent value sampled is $x_t = [\theta_{1,t} \ \theta_{2,t} \ \theta_{3,t} \ \theta_{4,t}]$. We next draw a new proposal state $x' = [\theta_1' \ \theta_2' \ \theta_3' \ \theta_4']$ with probability density $p(x'|x_t)$, which is the probability of having $[\theta_1' \ \theta_2' \ \theta_3' \ \theta_4']$ (i.e. their joint probability) knowing $x_t$.

A common and practical assumption is to assume that parameters are independent, which means that $p(x'|x_t) = p(\theta_1'|\theta_{1,t})p(\theta_2'|\theta_{2,t})p(\theta_3'|\theta_{3,t})p(\theta_4'|\theta_{4,t})$.

A nice example is the following paper : Bird, A. D., Wall, M. J., & Richardson, M. J. (2016). Bayesian inference of synaptic quantal parameters from correlated vesicle release. Frontiers in computational neuroscience, 10, 116.

They compute the posterior joint distribution of having six parameters using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. They even provide the JULIA and MATLAB code they used, which is available in the "Supplementary Material" section.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

> ... you could direct me to some good literature

I found [Chib, Greenberg (1995)](http://web1.sph.emory.edu/users/hwu30/teaching/statcomp/papers/chibGreenbergMH.pdf) insightful for understanding the MH algorithm.

> but I do not understand how to accept and reject samples

One quick and dirty solutoin is: sample one variable at a time, conditioning on every other variable (and data). i.e., sample $\theta_1 | \theta_{2:4}, x$, then $\theta_2 | \theta_1, \theta_{3:4}, x$, ..., and $\theta_4 | \theta_{1:3}, x$. That constitutes to one sample from the posterior. That is if you want $1000$ samples from the posterior, you would repeat the above procedure $1000$ times.

This is sometimes called Metropolised Gibbs, but as the paper suggests, it is really just MH. You should also be wary of potential [modes of failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling#Failure_modes).